# I need help fixing my C++ program - No errors, Not printing what I want it to

Tags: c++

My program is not printing out "123" when I enter "qwe" there are no error messages. Just this: [Unhandled exception at 0x78E7F2F6 (ucrtbased.dll) in TextEncode.exe: An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDyed.png)
and when i try to run it it says: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVdd8.png)

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

int main()
{
  string input;
  string output;
  cout << "please input your text..." << endl;

  cin >> input;

  for (int length = input.length(); length != 0; length--)
  {
    if (input[length] == 'Q' || input[length] == 'q')
    {
      cout << "1";
    }
    else if (input[length] == 'W' || input[length] == 'w')
    {
      cout << "2";
    }
    else if (input[length] == 'E' || input[length] == 'e')
    {
      cout << "3";
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The import statments are missing from your example, can you add it

Comment: Read [more about C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp), the documentation of your C++ compiler (perhaps [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/)...) and of your debugger (perhaps [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)....)

Comment: And study for inspiration some open source program similar to yours (e.g. on [github](http://github.com/) or [gitlab](http://gitlab.com/)...)

Comment: `input[input.length()]` is tricky when it is UB and when it is not, so it's simply best to start from `int length = input.length() - 1;`

Comment: `for(int length = input.length(); length != 0; length--)` get a pen and paper and write down what indices this loop will access.

Comment: @Eljay Not since C++11, and even before it was fine if used with `const std::string`. I think MSVC is overly proactive here (or OP uses C++98 for some reason).

Comment: That thing sounds like an error to me...

Comment: If you look at the picture its going from `length()+1` to 0. Thats different from the example. MSVC is doing exactly the right thing here.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen • Thank you, I learn something new everyday.  [`string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at)

Comment: It seems that the code you have posted here, is different from the code you're compiling (as seen in the image you posted). Please make it consistent.

Comment: Just a quick note here since I've seen this "problem" some times. You _can_ copy and paste your code into the question. There is no need to type it again. That's often a source of typos that lead to inconsistentencies between code and described behaviour. Please [edit] your question to show a true [mre] with emphasis on the reproducible part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This loop:

```
for(int length = input.length(); length != 0; length--)
```

iterates from `input.length()` to `1`. However the valid indices are `input.length() - 1` to `0`. Indexing into a `std::string` with the length of the string will return the `\0` character, which is not what you want. Note that before c++11, indexing into this position invokes undefined behavior, and indexing into `length + 1` for *any* range is always undefined behavior.

Your loop needs to be:

```
for(int length = input.length() - 1; length != -1; length--)
```

---

From c++20 the simple way to write this loop would be:

```
for (auto c : input | std::views::reverse) {
  std::cout << c; // for example
}
```

Comment: @churill Oh, yes, I think you're right. I wonder why an exception is being thrown then?

Comment: Changing to `input.at(length)` throws std::out_of_range.

Comment: @Eljay That's weird, it seems well defined for `std::string`.

Comment: @cigien Yep, see the linked picture, the original code has `for(int length = input.length() + 1;` which is indeed UB and worth an exception.

Comment: `at` doesn't allow access to `input.at(length)`, but `input[length]` has defined behavior in C++11.  Go figure.

Comment: @Eljay But the [ref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at) says "*If pos == size(), a reference to the character with value CharT() (the null character) is returned.*"

Answer (score 1):

The most important thing to know about C & C++ arrays is that they start from `0`. That means that the index of the last member is always one less than what you think it is.

If you have an array of size `3`, then the elements are numbered `0`, `1` and `2`. And C++ `string`s are no different. If you try to access the `length()` element of a `string`, you are accessing one *past* the string.

Also, I recommend you don't call the variable in your `for` loop `length`: that's the "length" of the string. A better name would be `index`. In fact, it's such a common name, that most people just call it `i`!

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, your indexing is off. However, I'd suggest solving this issue the C++ way, with an iterator loop. Those can handle the indexing *for* you. Where `.begin()` / `.end()` are the *forward* iterators, `.rbegin()` / `.rend()` are the *reverse* iterators of a container.

```
  for (auto it = input.rbegin(); it != input.rend(); ++it )
  {
    switch (*it)
    {
      case 'Q':
      case 'q':
        cout << "1";
        break;
      case 'W':
      case 'w':
        cout << "2";
        break;
      case 'E':
      case 'e':
        cout << "3";
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
```

(Using a switch instead of if - else if is a matter of taste; I find it more readable this way, and there *might* be a small perfomance increase in there if the compiler didn't optimize the multiple `if` conditions.)

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing an invalid position (accessing index  >= size  gives undefined behaviour for <= c++11, [ref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at) ) as the first iteration will use position `input.length()` whereas the last index is `input.length()-1`

To fix this undefined behaviour, you can change your for loop to

```
for(int length = input.length()-1; length >= 0; length--)
```

Comment: Bad things will happen in this implementation if empty string is entered. End condition should be either `length >=0` or `length != -1`

Comment: Hey, the link says its undefined till cpp++11, I have updated my answer to reflect the same. Thanks a lot for the suggestion

Comment: Thanks @Yksisarvinen, that was a good catch, fixed the answer